# The Dark Tower: Unwritten Version?

Tags: stephen-king, the-dark-tower

Based on clues throughout the original edition of The Gunslinger, can we reconstruct the "lost" version of the story that was foreshadowed there?  Have Stephen King, Robin Furth, or Bev Vincent commented on the "lost" version?

Comment: I'm afraid if King really planned back then what would be later then we would get that story, but we didn't...

Comment: Hmm, there would be no Crimson King, but Beast. Maerlyn would be another villain - Man in Black would stay dead. 2 book wouldn't differ much but later... but it's only speculation.